# Android App not compatible with own Devices

Tags: android, cordova, device, incompatibility

Im currently developing an App with Cordova and tested it on my android devices (Chuwi Hi8(4.4) and Homtom HT6(5.1)) and the app worked fine on them. now i published the apk, but the appstore tells me the app is incompatible with all my devices (developer console says ~10000 are compatible). Also i cant find my models in the list of devices in the developer console (Device Compatibility => All Devices). Now it doesnt shock me that google doesnt know these chinese Phones, but i can install other apps on them, so these developers must have been able to make their app compatible with my devices.

this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10101" android:versionName="1.1.0" package="de.codolith.venuerater" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
</manifest>
```

i cant see any reason why my app is not compatible with my devices. It also says its not compatible with Bluestacks which is shows as "Unknown Device" in the store.

does anyone have an idea what could be the problem here?

//edit: i just checked and i can find it on my devices, but why does it say its incompatible in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be due to camera requirements. What size is your apk? if it's too large the device might not have enough internal storage. Also are you located in a restricted country?

You don't want to require a camera, this permission requires a rear camera. This will allow it to work on devices that don't have a rear camera.

Pre Android 4.2:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
```

Android 4.2+

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: the package is only 3.3MB. im located in germany, so i guess no. well but my app kinda needs a rear camera. also my devices have cameras. rear and front. also i rather ask for an image file from my app and the normal camera screen opens to take a picture. i dont know if the camera thing is even necessary.